# Kotlin: naming parameters in lambda

Tags: kotlin, lambda

Please ignore the actual "functionality" and concentrate more on the use of lambda here as I am hacking around with lambdas, let, also, run etc to get a feeling for Kotlin.

```
val listener : (String?)->String = {
            val s2 = it?.also {
            }
                ?: "Null"
            statusText.text=s2
            s2
        }
```

So this assignment of a lambda to "listener" is just fine.

Could someone tell me why I am unable to assign a name to the first (and only) parameter eg.

```
  val listener : (s: String?)->String = {
            val s2 = s?.also {
            }
                ?: "Null"
            statusText.text=s2
            s2
        }
```

In the line "val s2=s?.also..."  the compiler complains that "s" is an unresolved reference. If so why is the naming of the parameter legal eg:

```
val listener : (s: String?)->String = {
```

Any explanation would be a great help to my understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
val listener : (s: String?) -> String = { s ->
    val s2 = s?.also {
    } ?: "Null"
    statusText.text=s2
    s2
}
```

or simply

```
val listener : (String?) -> String = { s ->
    val s2 = s?.also {
    } ?: "Null"
    statusText.text=s2
    s2
}
```

Note that using `return` in the mambda is incorrect, too.

Comment: Yeah cut and paste hell re:return. I altered that before I saw your reply. Thanks. Though I do see there is an explicit way to use return in lambdas eg return @listener s2, though I am yet to try that. I'll mark your lesson as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: What sort of situations would we want to name the parameter then (i.e. is there any benefit)?

Comment: When I want to use a named parameter: when the lambda takes more than one. Is this something frowned upon? That aside I made my point that this is just experimenting with Kotlin to get a feeling - not specifically to solve an issue.

Comment: I'd also like to repeat the Q about what my initial attempt naming s in lambda parameter type declarations was doing?

Comment: When a function takes a function as argument for example, or returns a function. Naming the arguments of the argument/returned function makes it easier to understand what the function does. See https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold-indexed.html for example: naming the Int argument `index` makes it easier to unerstand what the argument represents.

Comment: Ah, yes. I failed to consider documentation/self-documenting code.

Comment: And multiple parameters?

Comment: @HörmannHH not really getting what you're asking here. If you think the code is clearer with named parameters, then name them. Whether there is only one parameter or several ones doen't make a difference.

Comment: I'm not questioning you. I am referring to Slaw. But naming parameters is frequently done and my Q was merely on how to do it properly: and you have answered. Thanks,

Comment: @HörmannHH My question was directed at JB with regards to naming the parameters in the function type itself (i.e. `(name: T) -> R`). Since the name appears unusable in code I was wondering why we would ever declare one, to which JB mentioned the benefits of documentation.